# Why sql query returns a value if where clause is integer with zero?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a mysql field type, its name is code and type is int(11) I use this doctrine dql:

```
     $dql = "SELECT u.id, u.password, u.lastLoginIp, u.lastLoginDate FROM Entities\User u WHERE u.status = '1' AND (u.code = ?1 OR u.email = :n OR u.secretKey = :n)";
     $query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
     $query->setParameter('n', $this->username);
     $query->setParameter(1, (int)$this->username);
     $query->setMaxResults(1);
     $results = $query->getArrayResult();
     print_r($results);
```

But whatever value, integer or string I pass as `$this->username`, it still finds a record with code field with value 0. Why this should happen? I probably have to add that code field is UNIQUE key in mysql.

Comment: seems you have some type in you code  ..   Entities\User and ?1 .. waht do you really mean  ???

Comment: This is a login screen I want to allow users to login either by email or membership code that is digits and another value secretKey. If in db there is a code with value 0, the dql catch it with whatever passed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you table is User
you should set  the param the same number of time you need eg:

```
$dql = "SELECT u.id, u.password, u.lastLoginIp, u.lastLoginDate 
    FROM User u WHERE u.status = '1' AND (u.code = :n0 OR u.email = :n1 OR u.secretKey = :n2)";
     $query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
     $query->setParameter('n0', $this->username);
     $query->setParameter('n1', $this->your_code);
     $query->setParameter('n2',  $this->your_key);
     $query->setMaxResults(1);
     $results = $query->getArrayResult();
     print_r($results);
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: whatever random! I blindly press keyboard alphanumeric and still a record with code with value 0 is returned.

Comment: have you used  the 3 setparam  .. properly  as in my code??